# Applying the model on validation data achieves higher performance than on test set. Is this possible?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, machine-learning-model, cross-validation, performance

I trained a binary cross-validated classification model and got high performance (about 90) on the test data but when I apply the model to new unseen data to see how to performs, i get even higher performance (about 98). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is unlikely, but it is possible. If we assume that you have no mistakes in the code, this simply means that the unseen data is easier for the model to classify compared to the test data. This can happen if the unseen data is more similar to the training data compared to the test data or if there are less extreme values.